# Select the same pairs of values from two tables

Tags: mysql, qsqlquery

I have 4 MySQL tables in my database:

1. `Users` (uid, name)
2. `Shops` (shopId, shopName)
3. `Reviews` (ReviewId, text, userId, shopId, rate, date)
4. `TransactionHistory` (transactionId, userId, shopId, Amount, date)

Users write their comments to shops in `Reviews` table. And user payment history in some shops is saved in the `TransactionHistory` table.

I need to select all users' reviews for some period in time if that users made payments in that shop at the same period in time.

1. `Select userId, shopId, rate, text, date from Review where date between "01.01.2019" and "01.02.2019" where shopId in (select distinct(shopId) from Shops)`
2. `Select userId, shopId, date from TransactionHistory where date between "01.01.2019" and "01.02.2019"`

So I have two result sets and some records have the same pair (userId, shopId) - that is what I want to get: all records from 1 SQL request, which pairs (userId, shopId) is present in 2 SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood that right, all you need is a join statement like this one:

```
   SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
                 ON (t2.a = t1.a AND t3.b = t1.b AND t4.c = t1.c)
```

Here is the resource https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

On your case inside the on statement would be what you want to be equal.

```
Select userId, shopId, rate, text, date from Review r join TransactionHistory th on (r.userId == th.userId and r.shopId == th.shopId) where r.date between "01.01.2019" and "01.02.2019" where r.shopId in (select distinct(shopId) from Shops)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name as userName, u.surname, s.name, rate, review, c.amount FROM `rsamazingapp.rsamazingapp.reviews` as r 
INNER JOIN `rsamazingapp.cashbacks` as c ON (r.uid = c.uid and r.shop_id = c.shop_id) 
INNER JOIN `rsamazingapp.shops` as s on (r.shop_id = s.shop_id)
INNER JOIN `rsamazingapp.users` as u on (r.uid = u.uid)
where r.shop_id in (select distinct shop_id from `rsamazingapp.shops`)
order by rate desc
```